# Laravel | Queue failed : Missing argument 1 for App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS:

Tags: php, laravel, parameters, constructor, laravel-5.4

All my jobs fail because of this strange error and can't figure out whats the problem here.

**Job**:

```
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/**
 * Create a new job instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public $fName, $lName, $colAmt, $colDate, $totalAmt, $balAmt, $dueDate, $mobile_no, $is_loan_complete;

public function __construct($fName, $lName, $colAmt, $colDate, $totalAmt, $balAmt, $dueDate, $mobile_no, $is_loan_complete)
{
    //
    $this->fName = $fName;
    $this->lName = $lName;
    $this->colAmt = $colAmt;
    $this->colDate = $colDate;
    $this->totalAmt = $totalAmt;
    $this->balAmt = $balAmt;
    $this->dueDate = $dueDate;
    $this->mobile_no = $mobile_no;
    $this->is_loan_complete = $is_loan_complete;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function handle($fName, $lName, $colAmt, $colDate, $totalAmt, $balAmt, $dueDate, $mobile_no, $is_loan_complete)
{
    //

            $username = "xxxxxxxxxx";
        $hash = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

        // Config variables. Consult http://api.textlocal.in/docs for more info.
        $test = "0";

        // Data for text message. This is the text message data.
        $sender = "xxxxx"; // This is who the message appears to be from.
        $numbers = $mobile_no; // A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers

        $message = "Dear ".$fName." ".$lName.", your payment of Rs. ".$colAmt." has been received on ".$colDate.".
    Total: Rs. ".$totalAmt.", Balance: ".$balAmt.", Due Date: ".$dueDate.". Thank You";
        // 612 chars or less
        // A single number or a comma-seperated list of numbers
        $message = urlencode($message);

        $data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
        $ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/?');
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        echo $result = curl_exec($ch); // This is the result from the API
        curl_close($ch);
        $this->pusher($result); 


}
```

From the error in my failed_jobs table **I notice that the handle function doesn't even run due the argument error**

**Exception thrown:**

```
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'Missing argument 1 for App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS::handle()' in C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\app\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS.php:42
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\app\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS.php(42): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Missing argumen...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 42, Array)
#1 [internal function]: App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS->handle()
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(30): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::Illuminate\Container\{closure}()
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(531): Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(94): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(114): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->Illuminate\Bus\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS))
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php(98): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#10 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler.php(43): Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher->dispatchNow(Object(App\Jobs\SendCollectionSMS), NULL)
#11 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job.php(69): Illuminate\Queue\CallQueuedHandler->call(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Array)
#12 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(291): Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\Job->fire()
#13 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(258): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->process('database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#14 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Worker.php(110): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->runJob(Object(Illuminate\Queue\Jobs\DatabaseJob), 'database', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#15 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(101): Illuminate\Queue\Worker->daemon('database', 'default', Object(Illuminate\Queue\WorkerOptions))
#16 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand.php(85): Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->runWorker('database', 'default')
#17 [internal function]: Illuminate\Queue\Console\WorkCommand->fire()
#18 C:\xampp\htdocs\financetest1\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\BoundMethod.php(30): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
```

I'm calling the job from a controller like :(sorry for the mess in below code but it works)

```
dispatch(new SendCollectionSMS(ucwords($collection->loan->customer->first_name), ucwords($collection->loan->customer->last_name), $collection->collected_amount, Carbon::parse($collection->created_at)->format('d-m-Y'), $collection->loan->loan_amount, ($collection->loan->loan_amount - $collection->loan->collected_amount), Carbon::parse($collection->loan->end_date)->format('d-m-Y'), $collection->loan->customer->mobile_no, false));
```

Now I am positive that the arguments which I am passing when creating a new job in my controller are proper but It seems there is an issue in the way I'm referencing the variables in my handler.

Whats going wrong here?

Comment: from where are you calling this method?

Comment: @B.Desai see my edit please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very old post, but for anyone who runs into this problem.

Your handle function doesn't need any variables

```
public function handle()
```

Within this function you can get your variables by calling them as followed:

```
$this->fName
```

If you still run into the "missing argument 1" problem: **Restart your artisan command**

```
php artisan queue:work
```

This took me a while to figure out, changing your Job file has no effect if your queue:work is already running.